# Rails params[:id] are not been sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, parameters

Rails 4

I have an Account and Note Model. I am trying to save a note that is related to the account.

Note Model

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Account Model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_mamy :notes
end
```

Routes:

```
 resources :accounts
 resources :notes

 get 'accounts/:id/new_note'  => 'notes#new'
```

notes_controller.rb

```
def new
  @note            = Note.new
  @note.account_id = params[:id]

  respond_with(@note)
end


def create
  @note = Note.new(note_params)
  @note.save

  repond_with(@note)
end

private
  def note_params
     params.require(:note).permit(:title, :description, :account_id, :opportunity_id, :created_by, :updated_by)
  end
end
```

When I GET ".../accounts/1/new_note" and POST the request, the note gets saved but @note.account_id = nil.

Why??

In my other Model Opportunities, with a similar behaviour and everything is OK.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for `@note.account_id = params[:account_id]` ?  Any reason why you're using a custom route instead of nested resources?

Comment: I really did not know about nested resources. I will give it a try. But I would like to understand why this way is not working for notes. It should be params[:id] and not params[:account_id] since that is the way I declared it on the Route.rb From what I understand, if I change to the solution you propose @note.account_id = params[:account_id] my route should look like this get 'accounts/:account_id/new_note' Which I just tried and does not work either

Comment: It seems a bit muddled to me. How are you performing the POST request?  In the routes you posted, nothing refers to notes_controller.rb which is defining your methods.

Comment: The POST is done through the standard POST   /notes notes#create. Maybe I forgot to clarify that there is a resources :notes

Comment: So I assume you have a `new_note` action in your accounts controller?  What's that look like?  Maybe you want the `new_note` action in accounts_controller.rb to look like the `new` action in the notes_controller?

Comment: No, I have a new method in my notes_controller. get 'accounts/:id/new_note'  => 'notes#new'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66428/discussion-between-lut-and-helios-de-guerra).

Answer (score 1):

You have two strategies you could take to take care of this.

Option 1. The best solution to this is to use nested attributes.  Your users will have one form that why can use to create data for both models in one user experience.  Check out the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for details.

In app/models/account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base # as usual
  has_many :notes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes
end
```

Update the "accounts_params" method in your app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb

```
private

def accounts_params
  params.require(:accounts).permit(--all the stuff you already have--, 
                                   notes_attributes: [
                                        :id, 
                                        :title, 
                                        :description, 
                                        :account_id, 
                                        :opportunity_id
                                   ])
end
```

Also in app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb, you would need to make two further small alterations - an extra line in the "new" and "edit" methods:

```
def new
  @account = Account.new
  @account.notes.build # adds an empty note to your new account.
end

def edit
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  @account.notes.build # add a new empty note
end
```

I assume you have a views/accounts/_form.html.erb in your project.  Assuming you wish to merge the user interfaces for accounts and notes, you would extend your _form.html.erb file to include the following (for example, this could go just before your submit button):

```
<%=f.fields_for :notes do |note| %>
  <div>
    <%= note.label :title %>
    <%= note.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= note.label :description %>
    <%= note.text_area :description, rows: 4 %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You would then be able to dispense with the custom routing setup and possibly the notes_controller (unless you need it for some other reason).

Option 2. You could have a dedicated notes_controller that handles create and update requests, and you could fine-tune it to redirect the user back to the accounts pages.  Not a "bad" way to go, but it has the disadvantages of "more" code and a second process for users to follow - manage accounts, and separately manage notes.  That's said, here's how you could do it.

a) Create a notes_controller with typical "create" and "update" methods inside.

b) At the end of these methods, they probably do something like this:

```
redirect_to @note
```

You would change this to:

```
redirect_to @note.account
```

This would bring you to localhost:3000/accounts/123 (assuming the note was attached to note No. 123.

c) You would build a app/views/notes/_form.html.erb file as a self-contained form.

d) In your app/views/accounts/show.html.erb file, you would add a new panel at the bottom of the page that listed all the notes for the specific account.

```
# app/views/accounts/show.html.haml
<h1>Account # <%= @account.id %></h1>
...
<p>
  <=% link_to 'back', accounts_url %> | <%= link_to 'edit', edit_account_url(@account) %>
</p>

<h2>Notes</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <% @account.notes.each do |note| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= note.title %></td>
      <td><%= note.description %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <%= form_for @account.notes.build do |f| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.text_field :title %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_area :description, rows: 4 %></td>
      <!-- add whatever fields you want in here -->
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="4"><%= f.submit 'Save' %></td></tr>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

To make this work, all you'd need in your routes file is:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :accounts # as before
resources :notes, only: [:create, :update]
```

And rails should handle the rest.

With either option, you'd probably want to fiddle around a bit to provide 'edit' and 'delete' functionality to your users.  Do a few sketches and ask your client / guinea-pig users what looks more intuitive for them.

Comment: Ok! This is how it looks with nested resources.   resources :accounts do resources :notes end. I get this error in my form, NoMethodError in Notes#new, undefined method `notes_path' for...  <%= simple_form_for(@note) do |f| %>

Comment: I have rewritten my original post so you get a clearer picture of how you could proceed.